# Adjective for a lamp that is turned on

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What adjective is common for a lamp that is turned on in contrast with a lamp that is turned off?

In fact, I try to find two antonym adjectives that are often used before lamp, when it gives light and when it is switched off.

Comment: lit and dark, no?

Comment: Candles and oil lamps are lit and extinguished.  Electric lamps are simply on and off.

Comment: a lamp can also be shining or not shining.

Comment: Some people say of electric lights that they are *lit* or *unlit* - though more usually *on* or *off*. More often you hear the like of *the room was dimly lit* etc.

Comment: The light is on, the light that is on..., is how to say it. the 'on' light is only using 'on' as a quoted label.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the context is about electric lamps.
Not very common, but an adjective which works to imply that the lamp is *giving light* is ***aglow***.

ODO:

> **[aglow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aglow)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> [predicative] **Glowing**
>
> ‘The lights are aglow in the windows, the sound of the Christmas
>   carols and the song we associate with the season of goodwill to all
>   men is with us once again.’

To imply that the lamp is *switched on* (not necessarily giving out light for the moment, examples being some types of lamps needing warm-up), an adjective which works is ***powered-up*** (*powered-down* for *switched off*).

ODO:

> **[powered-up](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/powered-up)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Using increased power, more powerful; **switched on**.

Comment: Side question: to my ear this adjective can only follow the noun. Is this true? If so, what rule us at play?

Answer (score 0):

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/switch_something_on) offers ***activate,*** among others, as a synonym for "switch something on." It may work, depending on the context.

Comment: The OP is looking for an adjective, not a verb. Activated light could work in some context and please focus on its adjective usage with examples.

Answer (score -1):

You could use **Illuminated** and **Unilluminated**

> #### Illuminated
>
> *adj.*
>
> - Supplied or brightened with light
> - Lit up

([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illuminated))
([CD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/illuminated))

> #### Unilluminated
>
> *adj.*
>
> - Not lit up or bright with light

([CD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unilluminated))

Comment: I think of illuminate as to shine a light on something rather than to emanate light from something.

Comment: The OP is looking for adjectives to be used before *Lamp*. An ***illuminated lamp*** does not insinuate that it's shining onto something. It means the lamp is supplying light. If *illuminate* is used as a verb, then it sometimes can insinuate *to shine* but an adjective form was asked for.

Comment: Ok, it is used this way in some tech manuals so I will upvote.

Comment: @Hank I don't disagree with your logic, but one seldom hears anyone talk about an *illuminated lamp*. Usually the context would make it clear whether the lamp was on or off. However if there was a need to point out that the lamp was giving light, I don't think I would use *lit* on its own. I would probably say something like *she was holding a brightly/dimly-lit lamp*. Neither *lit* nor *illuminated* seem to cut the mustard for me.

Comment: @WS2 I don't necessarily use either in my everyday language. I usually provide a context that tells the reader/listener the status of the light without using an adjective directly before it. But, given the OP's request, *illuminated* would be the word I would use if I were forced to specifically use an adjective before *lamp*. But that's just me personally. I do understand your stance, though. It is a valid one.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning here that in a technical sense, a lamp and a light are not the same thing. And when a status lamp is illuminated, it is the *status* that is illuminated. "E-08:  Strat Alert, Fault indicator illuminated, active VRSA 26 (site on diesel generator), OZ illuminated hard or cycling, Mnx on site, two security guards topside with Mnx team in rest status in on-site camper." http://timhebert.blogspot.com/2010/12/off-alert-echo-flight-0845.html